# Connect to a device through a serial port and send a command, but nothing is returned

Tags: c#, serial-port, port

I need to connect to a sensor through a serial port and read some data off it. I connect to it and send the command, but nothing is returned from the device, instead a Timeout exception is thrown. Similar questions here on stackoverflow use the OnDataReceived event, i tried that and it did not work. The parameters i used to initialize and the command i send work as expected on Putty.

-- what am i missing here

```
void Read()
{
        SerialPort serialPort = new SerialPort("COM1", 9600, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);

        try
        {
            serialPort.Handshake = Handshake.XOnXOff;
            serialPort.Encoding = new ASCIIEncoding();
            serialPort.ReadTimeout = 1000;
            serialPort.WriteTimeout = 900;
            serialPort.Open();


            serialPort.WriteLine("TEMP");
            MessageBox.Show("Reading");
            MessageBox.Show(serialPort.ReadLine());
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
            serialPort.Close();
        }
}
```

Thank you

Comment: Does it work with `echo test > com1:` from command line (or with a proper terminal application)? Moveover (but this may just be a problem in your example) are you sure your device will reply with UNICODE text as expected by `ReadLine`?

Comment: Are you sure that the device is responding? Did you confirm this using a [terminal](http://realterm.sourceforge.net/)?

Comment: Yes, i tested the device through Putty.exe, i just tried echo test > com1 , it returned nothing

Comment: @Adriano Yes, i tested the device through Putty.exe, i just tried echo test > com1 , it returned nothing

Comment: If putty doesn't receive anything either, then the problem is with the device (baud rate, hand shaking, etc.), isn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest that the problem is with the encoding you're using. To check if that's the problem use a sniffer of your choice to see that the bytes transferred on your application are the same as on putty.

Only be sure that you're actually trying to read the bytes when using a sniffer because if you don't they won't be shown on the output.

If that doesn't show you anything you can try to change your ReadLine() method to ReadByte() to ensure that there's no problem with the reading type that you're using.

Serial port sniffers

- http://www.serialmon.com/
- virtual-serial-port.org/products/serialmonitor/?gclid=CInI2ZPL_bsCFaxr7Aod8S4A8w
- www.hhdsoftware.com/device-monitoring-studio

Comment: Sorry that the two last links are not complete but i don't have enough reputation to post more than one link

Comment: It was an encoding problem. Thank you. I thought i marked this as an answer years ago.

Answer (score 2):

```
   serialPort.Handshake = Handshake.XOnXOff;
```

Maybe that's correct, it is pretty unusual.  But real devices almost always pay attention to the hardware handshake signals, in *addition* to an Xon/Xoff flow control protocol.  The DTR (Data Terminal Ready) and RTS (Ready To Send) signals have to be turned on before the device is convinced that it is connected to a real computer.  A program like Putty will always turn them on, your program does not.

Add these two required lines:

```
   serialPort.RtsEnable = true;
   serialPort.DtrEnable = true;
```

And ensure that the serialPort.NewLine property correctly matches the end-of-message character used by the device.  Temporarily use ReadExisting() instead to avoid getting bitten by that detail, don't leave it that way.

Comment: Many simple devices only use two wires for serial communication. I wouldn't say it's that unusual to have no hardware handshaking (and even if there is support for it, it's often configurable).

Comment: Many good devices, particularly the kind that are used in lab or industrial applications, *do* use handshaking.  And of course Occam's Razor always applies here, if the OP would be using a "simple" device then he would not have asked the question.

Comment: I agree that many of them do use handshaking, but I've written parsers for a bunch of measurement devices which don't. And one might say that Occam's Razor would say "why use more than 2 wires if you don't have to". :) But the answer is useful like your answers usually are, this is just my opinion.